# Tiled surfaces in kitchen and bathroom...how do I refresh it to make it look better and/or newer?

Tags: bathroom, tile, kitchen-counters

Please refer to the following photos.
[image]

[image]

The kitchen counter looks a bit weathered/worn and the finish is matte.
The bathroom floor also looks a bit weathered/worn and the finish is also matte.
The bathroom counter is actually not bad, but could use a touchup.

What are some things that I can do to clean up and refinish the kitchen countertop, the bathroom floor and the bathroom countertop?
Do I need to re-glaze tiles?

Should I give all the tiled surfaces a scrub down as a starting point?

Comment: There are some enamel-epoxy products that can be painted on, but I think in the truest sense of the word glazing pottery would require a kiln. Do you possibly mean re-grouting? For things that need to be brightened and/or whitened, bleach is astoundingly effective.

Comment: It is tough to bring back the original luster / shine of tile. There are several high gloss sealers that can be applied that may help but these do require the tile and grout to be cleaned with a strong cleaner and then fully rinsed. Some of the high gloss sealers take 2-3 coats to give close to the original shine. I have used a Dupont high gloss product that was middle of the price range but did work well ~ $90 per gallon that may be more than you need.